# Why does $1234^{1234^{1234}\ \bmod\ 10^{10}}$ = $1234^{1234^{1234}\ \bmod \ \phi(10^{10})}$

Tags: modular-arithmetic, totient-function

I know that if we want the last 10 decimal digits of $$1234^{1234^{1234}}$$ 
we should compute $1234^{1234^{1234} \bmod\ \phi(10^{10})} \bmod 10^{10}$ to keep the exponent small.  And that technically, $1234^{1234^{1234}\ \bmod\ 10^{10}} \bmod 10^{10}$ is incorrect.  Yet they are equal.  Why?

Comment: What do you mean by "why"?

Comment: I mean why are they equal for these particular constants even though the approach, in general, is flawed.  Is this an artifact of base 10?  Does 1234 have a particular property?  Or does this always work for any base and any constant?

Answer (score 3):

$\phi(10^{10})=4\cdot 10^9$ divides $2\cdot 10^{10}$, so we'd still get a right answer if we considered the exponent mod $2\cdot 10^{10}$. Now we note that every equivalence class mod $10^{10}$ corresponds to 2 equivalence classes mod $2\cdot 10^{10}$ so that should give you about 50-50 odds of getting it the right result (if there's not more going on).

In general of course $\phi(n)$ doesn't nearly divide $n$, as it does here, so it's pretty specific to this problem (although it does generalize to other powers of $10$).

Edit: There is in fact slightly more going on since while $\phi(n)$ is the order of the multiplicative group modulo $n$, if the group isn't cyclic, it's not necessarily true that the least common multiple of all the orders in the group is $\phi(n)$. Denoting the multiplicative group modulo $n$ by $R_n$, the Chinese Remainder Theorem tells us that $R_{10^{10}}=R_{2^{10}}\times R_{5^{10}}$ and there's a nice structure theorem for these groups that tells us that $R_{2^{10}}=C_2\times C_{2^8}$, where $C_n$ is the cyclic group with $n$ elements. In particular the least common multiple of the orders of elements of $R_{2^{10}}$ is $2^8$ instead of $2^9$ so it'll be generally correct to take the exponent mod $\frac{\phi(10^{10})}{2}$ which does divide $10^{10}$.

Comment: I just tried it for 1000 values other than 1234, and it always works.  Assuming your argument above is correct, there is only a 1 in $2^{1000}$ chance that was just luck, so there is something missing here still.

Comment: You're right. I've worked it out fully now.

Comment: Does it affect your answer at all that 1234 $\not\in R_{10^{10}}$?

Comment: Also, the LCM of all group orders (for periodic groups) is called the "exponent" of the group.  Although this seems to not be very well-known (for example, Wolfram Alpha appears to not know the term).

Comment: Well, uh, the basic method is already faulty (in that $10^{\phi(10^{10})+1}\equiv 0$ mod $10^{10}$ and not $10$ mod $10^{10}$. My answer isn't particularly more wrong.

Comment: It's true that, if $a\in 10^{10}$ then you can say $a^b = a^{b \bmod\ \phi(10^{10})}$.  It's also true you can instead say $a^b = a^{b\ \bmod\ \phi(10^{10})/4}$ since I believe $\phi(10^{10})/4$ is the exponent of the group.  For $a\not\in 10^{10}$ the assertion in the question above isn't faulty unless $a$ is a multiple of 10, and 1234 is not.  You have given a proof, however, that doesn't provide for this.

Comment: The method requires $a$ and $10^{10}$ to be coprime, not just for $a$ to not be a multiple of 10. It is not true that $2^{\phi(10^{10})+1}\equiv 2$mod $10^{10}$; it's just really likely you'll get the right answer anyway since most equivalence classes mod $10^{10}$ are greater than $10$.

Answer (score 0):

**Earlier incorrect post:** Note that $\phi(10^{10}) = 2 \cdot 10^9$ divides $10^{10}$.

**Correction:** My mistake, $\phi(10^{10}) = 2^{11} \cdot 5^9$, as several commenters noticed.

Let $A: = {1234^{1234}}, \; a:= A \mod 10^{10}, \; b: = A \mod \phi(10^{10})$. To show that $1234^a \equiv 1234^b \mod 10^{10}$, it is enough to show that  $1234^a \equiv 1234^b \mod 2^{10}$ and  $1234^a \equiv 1234^b \mod 5^{10}$ and use the Chinese Remainder Theorem.

Now clearly  $1234^a \equiv 1234^b  \equiv 0 \mod 2^{10}$, since $a, \, b > 10$.

To show  $1234^a \equiv 1234^b \mod 5^{10}$, we use Euler's Theorem and thus must show that $a \equiv b \mod \phi(5^{10})$. Now $n = \phi(5^{10}) = 4 \cdot 5^9$, which divides both $M = 10^{10}$ and $N = \phi(10^{10})$. Consequently $$
a \mod n \equiv (A \mod M) \mod n \equiv (A \mod N ) \mod n = b \mod n \, .\
$$

Therefore the two computations give the same result.

Comment: No, $\phi(10^{10}) = 4\cdot 10^9$.

Comment: $\phi(10^{10}) = \phi(2^{10})\phi(5^{10}) = 2^9 \cdot 4\cdot 5^9$.

Comment: Thanks, it has now been corrected.